# Plotting Association Rules Error

Tags: r, plot, arules

I am currently learning about association rules in R
Below is my code

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
test[] <- lapply(test, factor)
rules <- apriori(test)

summary(rules)
plot(rules)
```

The code falls over when i try to plot it with the error:

> Error: package ‘arules’ 1.1-9 is loaded, but >= 1.2.0 is required by ‘arulesViz’
>
> In addition: Warning message:
> package ‘arulesViz’ was built under R version 3.1.3

I tried updating all my packages but i am being told everything is up to date

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: What version of R are you running? Possibly you need to update R; the latest version of `arules` is 1.4.1.

Comment: Thank you @David_B, I updated [R](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/03/updating-r-from-r-on-windows-using-the-installr-package/) and it works now. Please add it as an answer and il tick it. Have a nice weekend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of R are you running? Possibly you need to update R; the latest version of arules is 1.4.1.